# Serverspec ssh results in: OS detection failed

Tags: ruby, ssh, rspec, serverspec

I just recently got an issue with the net-ssh gem usage for my Linux remote host. To exclude any strange environment a clean `serverspec-init` was performed with Linux/SSH options selected and the corresponding remote host. Furthermore I adjusted the spec_helper.rb to the following:

```rb
require 'serverspec'
require 'net/ssh'

set :backend, :ssh

host = ENV['TARGET_HOST']
options = Net::SSH::Config.for(host)
options[:user] ||= "MYUSER"
options[:password] ||= "MYPASSWORD"
set :sudo_password, "MYPASSWORD"
set :host,        options[:host_name] || host
set :ssh_options, options
```

And this resulted in the following output:

```rb
C:\Users\JumpStart\Documents\Repositories\connecttest>rake spec
C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I'C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-support-3.9.2/lib';'C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib' 'C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/exe/rspec' --pattern 'spec/MYHOST/*_spec.rb'

An error occurred while loading ./spec/MYHOST/sample_spec.rb.
On host `MYHOST'
Failure/Error:
  describe package('httpd'), :if => os[:family] == 'redhat' do
    it { should be_installed }
  end
NotImplementedError:
  OS detection failed.

# ./spec/MYHOST/sample_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.

Finished in 0.00006 seconds (files took 11.86 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples

C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I'C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-support-3.9.2/lib';'C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib' 'C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/exe/rspec' --pattern 'spec/MYHOST/*_spec.rb' failed
```

I can normally ssh connect manually to the host with the username/password.

Comment: According to the source code, this would imply your remote host is running some rare/unknown operating system that e.g. does not contain files like `/etc/redhat-release` and is unable to execute `uname -a`. Alternatively, are you doubly specifying a target host?

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thanks for the fast reply. Unfortunately this is not the case. The OS is a normal Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I had working tests like a week ago for the same host. The TARGET_HOST env variable is set correctly (according to puts debugging in helper_spec.rb).